# Why is my "Saved Games" folder not visible?

Tags: windows-10, user-folders

I try to modify a file in the 'Save game' folder which is in

```
C:\users\myuser\Save Games\
```

I enabled the check boxes to show hidden files and even system data, but the folder is not visible. I can only access it via `CMD`.

Comment: When I can access a hidden folder on my PC, it usually is my anti-virus that blocks it. Restarting the PC solves it. It might also be your case.

Comment: Maybe it acquired a different display name and "hiding in plain sight". Click in the **Explorer** Address bar & type: `shell:SavedGames`. Does any folder open?

Comment: try right from the Start button. Click, type `%USERPROFILE%\saved games` hit Enter.